# PHP Date issue when year changes

Tags: php, date

I'm a newb with `PHP` and code in general, so please forgive any sloppiness...

What I've made here is an expiring link tool so someone can make their links expire past a certain date (`$getdate`).

If the person clicks the link BEFORE the `$getdate` then they'll be passed on to the `$goodurl`.

If the person clicks the link AFTER the `$getdate` then they'll be passed onto the $expired url.

An example URL would be: https://expiring.click/?d=02/24/2017&g=https://example.com/deal/&e=https://example.com/no-deal/

Hopefully that makes some sense.

Now, this code works with one exception ... when the current year is different than the expiration year.

When that happens, people are always sent to the `$goodurl`.

So, if my link was set to expire in 02/02/2016 and I clicked on it today (02/23/2017) ... I would see the `$goodurl` even tho the expiration date is over a year ago.

I can't figure it out to save my life.

Hopefully one of you nice folks can help!

Thanks.

```html
<?php
$getdate = htmlspecialchars($_GET["d"]); // Date Good Through
$sentdate = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($getdate)); // Make sure date is in correct format
$goodurl = htmlspecialchars($_GET["g"]); // Good URL
$expiredurl = htmlspecialchars($_GET["e"]); // Expired URL
$expired = htmlspecialchars($_GET["expired"]); // For Expired = y

// Date Stuff
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$date = date('m/d/Y');
$datetime = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
$tomorrow = date('m/d/Y',strtotime($date . "+1 days"));

// Formula Stuff
if ($expired != "y" && !empty($getdate)){
 if ($sentdate < $date){ //expired
  if (empty($expiredurl)) {
   $link = "https://expiring.click/?expired=y";
  } else {
   $link = $expiredurl;
  }
 } else if ($sentdate >= $date){ //in date
  $link = $goodurl;
 }
 header( 'Location: '.$link ) ;
} else if ($expired == "y") {
 echo "Sorry, this link has expired.";
} else {
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to  compare after using strtotime() funtion on both sent date and date.

$sentdate = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($getdate));

should be

```
$sentdate = strtotime(date("m/d/Y", strtotime($getdate)));
```

And 
$date = date('m/d/Y');

should be

```
$date = strtotime(date('m/d/Y'));
```